# Cassandra Server starting issue on windows 10 machine

Tags: windows, cassandra

I am trying to run Cassandra Server on my Windows 10 machine.
In this machinge:

**Java**: java version "1.8.0_202"
**Python**: Python 2.7.16

**Cassandra**: apache-cassandra-3.11.11

Facing this problem

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this dir exist? `c:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.11\logs\ `

Comment: Also for the future, put error messages in as code-formatted text, and not an image.

Comment: Mr @Aaron no there is no folder with this name, but I just download apache-cassandra-3.11.11-bin.tar.gz from the official site and unzipped it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installed java 1.8 and Python 2.7

Set the environment variables path for java, Python, and Cassandra.

```
Open Windows PowerShell as administrator mode and run:

     => set-executionpolicy -executionpolicy unrestricted

Open Windows CMD as administrator mode and run:

     =>cassandra
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was able to get this to work.

I downloaded [Apache Cassandra 3.11.11](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/cassandra/3.11.11/apache-cassandra-3.11.11-bin.tar.gz) on my Windows 10 machine, with a recent patch of Java 8.  I untar'd it into a directory under my user (`c:\Users\aploetz\local\`).  In trying to run it, I was greeted with one of the same errors I saw in your edit history:

```
WARNING! Powershell script execution unavailable.
   Please use 'powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted'
   on this user-account to run cassandra with fully featured
   functionality on this platform.
```

So, I found my local Windows Powershell in the Start menu, and was sure to select "Run as Administrator."  With that window opened, I ran this command:

```
> set-executionpolicy -executionpolicy unrestricted
```

Not the most secure thing to do, but unfortunately Cassandra just won't run on Windows without that.  From there, running `cassandra` from the `bin` directory worked.

TBH, this complexity is part of what drove Windows support to be dropped from the Apache Cassandra project.  The easiest way to run Cassandra on Windows is via [Docker](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop) or some other other containerization platform.

```
> docker pull cassandra:3.11
> docker run --name my-cassandra -d -p 9042:9042 cassandra:3.11
```

**Edit 20211214**

I led a [webinar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eMKXiItZ0Q4&list=PL2g2h-wyI4Sor6qaGlbRv1htx0hmgmIs5&index=6) around addressing the recent licensing changes with Docker Desktop, discussing how to [run Apache Cassandra on Windows w/ Minikube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eMKXiItZ0Q4&list=PL2g2h-wyI4Sor6qaGlbRv1htx0hmgmIs5&index=6).  Check the [Git repo](https://github.com/aar0np/cassandra_minikube) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Aaron's response, there is very limited Windows support in Cassandra 3.11 and there are several known issues that will not be fixed due to limitations in the operating system.

Furthermore, Windows support has been completely dropped in Cassandra 4.0 due to lack of maintainers and testing ([CASSANDRA-16171](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16171)).

As a workaround, we recommend the following:

- [Deploy Cassandra in Docker](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/quickstart.html)
- Deploy Cassandra in a VM using software like VirtualBox
- Deploy [K8ssandra.io](https://k8ssandra.io/get-started/)

If you just want to build apps with Cassandra as a backend, [Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/3jdZVbU) has a free tier that lets you launch a Cassandra cluster in a few clicks with no credit card required. Cheers!